# Dependency Injection in a WPF Application with Many Windows

Tags: dependency-injection

Is it "correct" to have many factories when using Dependency Injection with a "line of business" application?  By, "line of business" application I mean an application like SalesForce.com or a CRM system with many functions and associated windows/forms.  Actually, SalesForce.com may be a bad example.  The HTTP GET/POST mechanic creates obvious composition roots at which to invoke the DI container.  But what of a long running WPF application, for example?  Creating the object graphs for all possible functions seems wasteful when many of them won't be invoked during that session or maybe never if that person's role limits their use of the application.

It would appear that the solution is to use the DI container to resolve each window/form as it is needed.  But:

1. This goes against the DI principle of only resolving at the composition root, in this case resolving the parent window at application start.
2. This would require a factories to create the windows/forms to prevent references to 
   the DI container in application code.  It seems that factories would multiply quickly.

This seems to increase rather than decrease complexity by requiring the creation of factories whose sole function create an "artificial" composition root to hide the call to the DI Resolve method.

I also understand that ideally factories should not reference the DI container, but in this case there is an object graph to resolve and not using the DI container would require me to resolve the dependecies myself, apparently defeating the purpose of using the DI container.

To be honest, the application isn't that complicated right now and the factories wouldn't complicate matters greatly.  However, I wrote this isolated application using DI as a learning exercise to introduce it to myself and the small dev team I am on.  Most of the team is unfamiliar with DI and will wonder at the effectiveness of DI when it required extra code and classes simply to hide the introduction of the DI container.

FWIW, I did pick up a copy of Mark Seemann's "Dependency Injection in .NET", but the WPF example seems too simple to cover this exact scenario, as might be expected in an introductory text.  His example has a single MVVM form created in the OnStartup event.

Any insight appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I run up against this all the time in creating Views/ViewModels in WPF and Silverlight.  In fact I recently made a comment on a post in Mark Seemann's blog along these lines:

[See my Comment at Monday, September 19, 2011 10:39:25 PM](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/09/19/MessageDispatchingWithoutServiceLocation.aspx).  (The post itself is interesting as well, discussing where Mark feels it is acceptable to reference the container.)

If you use Castle Windsor for DI, you can use the TypedFactoryFacility which allows you to avoid referencing the container in your factory.

My general approach when *not* using Windsor is to just create a generic abstract factory that *does* call Resolve() and be done with it.  This still feels like service location to me (i.e. it feels "wrong"), but I have yet to find another (non-Windsor) solution that isn't painful to code and maintain.